# MySQL: Select distinct combinations accross two rows, not double counting

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I have the following table

```
  dc  rc
----------
  AE  GB
  DE  US
  CN  DE
  DE  TT
  US  DE
  GB  AE
```

I want to select all unique dc, rc combinations, but irrespective of the order. In particular, the MySQL select should return

```
  dc  rc
----------
  AE  GB
  DE  US
  CN  DE
  DE  TT
```

i.e. it should not double count AE - GB and DE - US. I found some similar issues, e.g. when the database is one of relationships which always show up twice (e.g. on [Filter SQL query by a unique set of column values, regardless of their order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977648/filter-sql-query-by-a-unique-set-of-column-values-regardless-of-their-order)). However, this is NOT the case here as there is no guarantee that the entry appears twice (in most cases it doesnt).

Clearly,

```
SELECT DISTINCT dc, rc FROM table GROUP BY dc, rc
```

will NOT do the trick.

I am grateful to any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

(EDITED, to include additional columns)

```
select dc, rc, min(other_column1), sum(other_column2) /*etc as required*/
from
(select dc, rc, other_column1, other_column2 from table where rc >= dc
 union all
 select rc, dc, other_column1, other_column2 from table where rc < dc) v
group by dc, rc
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesnt work. It gives me exactly the same as when I run "SELECT distinct dc, rc FROM table"

But maybe the set operations are the way to go. 

I thought it somehow could be solved by using something like NOT EXISTS or EXISTS in the SQL statement.

This would allow only to select the distinct rc, dc but not if a particular rc, dc combination has already been selected. 

I seem to not be able to manage this however...

Any suggestions?

Comment: @user1053779, are you using the dataset you provided in the example? when I do so, I get your desired output dataset.

Comment: @Mark:
Its not exactly the same dataset, you are right. I tried using the sample dataset I gave as well and I got the correct result.

How can I make you query work? Or why does it not work in the actual table? It basically does not get rid of the double entries that are the other way around... i.e. it gives me both US - DE and DE - US combinations...

I dont quite understand. Thanks a lot for your help!

The table has a bunch of more colums, but essentially I am selecting the two subcolums dc, rc that have the same structure as the sample dataset.

Comment: @devmag: it's the additional columns that are causing your problem - you need to decide what you want to do with them (sum them, select their minimum, maximum, average or other aggregates, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that should provide the same answer as Mark's:

```
SELECT A.DC, A.RC
FROM tab A
LEFT JOIN tab B
 ON A.DC = B.RC
AND A.RC = B.DC
AND A.DC >= B.DC
WHERE B.RC IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

sql server is my thing so you might need to translate, but this should do it

```
Select Distinct dc, rc
From
( Select dc,rc From SomeTable
  Union
  Select rc,dc From SomeTable
) BothWays
```

Union effectively does a distinct, so it should work.

Comment: yes, it somehow does not work. I guess the key is the "bothways", which may not be available in MySQL.

I already thought of maybe creating a field for each combination that concatenates the strings and then orders the strings alphabetically. This could give me something that would be identical for

US - DE
DE - US

and thus, I could do a distinct on this "new identifier". THis identifier may not be unique however. But there must be a way to do this in a clever query.

Comment: @devmag: BothWays is a table alias.